# INVALID HEAP ARGUMENT: allocated with operator new[], freed with operator delete

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-leak-detector

I am using Dr. Memory to debug my code. It gives me the following message:

```
INVALID HEAP ARGUMENT: allocated with operator new[], freed with operator delete
```

However, whenever I use `delete[]` instead of `delete`, it gives me the same error. The error occurs in the following lines:

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    delete data[x];
}
delete [] data;
```

Variable `data` is being allocated as follows:

```
data = new char*[width];
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
{
    data[i] = new char[1];
}
```

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: That's because you're still using `delete` to delete things allocated with `new[]`.

Comment: Allocating a single character as an array? That's a paddlin'. In fact raw memory abuse in general's a paddlin', why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

You currently allocate the elements with

```
data[i] = new char[1];
```

and delete them with

```
delete data[x];
```

As you allocated them with the `new[]` you need to delete them with `delete []`.

```
delete [] data[x];
```

Comment: i am doing that. but as soon as i do that it tells me that i should have used delete instead of delete[]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some other call to `new` that just does `data[i] = new char` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the second `new[]` (`data[i] = new char[1]`)  too:

```
for (int x=0; x<width; ++x){
    delete [] data[x];
}
delete [] data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using c++, and not C...

Re-factor the code to use the STL and std::string to create vectors of std::strings in the program.

Use of std::string will likely eliminate the memory leak.